# From Gaussian Curvature to the Surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^2$, and $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R$, we know that the graph of function $f$ is a surface in $\mathbb R^3$.

Suppose, we just know the Gaussian Curvature $k$ of the surface and the value/behavior of $f$ along/restriction on the boundary $\partial \Omega$.

**Q**: How to find the $f$?

PS: Any computational method  is also welcome.

Comment: How is it related to covering spaces?

Comment: @JohnMa No idea, someone modified the tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem of prescribed Gauss curvature, one of the classic examples of a [PDE of Monge-Ampere type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monge%E2%80%93Amp%C3%A8re_equation). See section "Applications" for the explicit PDE. It is a nonlinear elliptic PDE and not so easy to solve in general, though there is a lot of modern research on the subject and Monge-Ampere equations overall.